# Iot Rule is sending the messages to SNS but SNS is unable to send notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, amazon-ses, rules

I am writing a rule in IoT core which sends messages to SNS and SQS. In SQS the data is being stored in queue successfully. But SNS is not sending an email. I have followed the same AWS documentation but of no use. I am tried in different accounts and also different email addresses. Can anyone solve this issue

Comment: Once your email is verified, there will be no issue I think. Just a few steps are needed.

Comment: I first created a topic in aws and then added subscription. My email... and then i verified my email. I then wrote an Iot rule which will send data to the same SNS topic that I created previously. I exactly followed the documentation.

Comment: I even tried sending the data from Iot core to SNS and then i gave the subscription as SQS. But still, it's not working. Can anyone try it once?

Comment: Connect your SNS to lambda and check the body of the event. It might be helpful.

Comment: "errorMessage":"Failed to publish SNS topic. The error received was Invalid parameter: Message Structure - No default entry in JSON message body

Comment: I am getting this error can anyone help me out

Comment: post your sns body sent from iot core.

Comment: Thank you I solved the issue. My SNS body does not have a default message.